# Text Detection for numbers only

Tags: android, google-vision, text-recognition

I'd like the new mobile vision text recognition API to scan for numbers or letters only. Does the API allow for this currently? Right now I do a lot of post processing to clean up errors like "b" is really a "6", or

If not now is there a plan for an API in the future?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it's not possible to provide a black or whitelist at the moment. It will be nice if they add this in the future. You can use the release notes (https://developers.google.com/vision/release-notes) to get informed.